# Displaying saved category checked in a plugin?

Tags: plugins, categories

I'm trying to display only saved category as checked other is unchecked. I am using a loop but it does not work properly. I create code like this:

```
     <tr>   
    <th><label><?php _e("Category:"); ?></label></th>
    <td>
    <?php 
$args = array(
                'child_of'                 => get_cat_ID(single_cat_title( '', false )),
                'orderby'                  => 'name',
                'order'                    => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty'               => 1,
                'hierarchical'             => 1,
                'exclude'                  => '',
                'include'                  => '',
                'number'                   => '',
                'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
                'pad_counts'               => false 

            ); 

     ?>
   <?php $categories = get_categories( $args ); ?>

    <?php
     $category_explode = get_the_author_meta( 'Category', $user->ID );
     //output 4,5,16 
      $cat_ex = explode(',',$category_explode); 
      foreach ($cat_ex as $cat_expld)   {

     foreach ($categories as $cat)  {

         ?>
     <label> <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" <?php if($cat_expld==$cat->cat_ID){  echo "checked='checked'"; } ?> value="<?php echo $cat->cat_ID; ?>" ><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?> 
     </label>
        <?php   } }  ?>  
         </td>
         </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question as follow:

```
foreach ($categories as $cat)   {
$category_explode = get_the_author_meta( 'Category', $user->ID );
//output 4,5,16 
$cat_ex = explode(',',$category_explode); 
?>
<label> <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="<?php echo $cat->cat_ID; ?>" <?php foreach ($cat_ex as $cat_expld)  { if($cat->cat_ID == $cat_expld){echo'checked="checked"';} }?> /><span> <?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?>

  </label>
     <?php  }    ?>
```